# Vee validate and zod not validating the form in nuxt3 project

Tags: javascript, typescript, vee-validate, nuxtjs3

I am trying to create a form and to validate its fields using `vee-validate` and `zod`
On a different form everything worked like a charm, but on this form nothing works and I don't understand why is that.

On my local machine, in the vue dev tools tab I can see something like this
[image]

The field is not under the `Form` and is marked as standalone. It other form this was not the case, the field was under `Form` and the validation worked

I tried to create a new project on stackblitz to see if in a default configuration it's working, but it appears that it's not working [here you can find it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vee-validate-not-working)

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `useForm` after `useField` declaration and this was causing the form to behave like this

so instead of this:

```js
const { errorMessage, meta, value: firstName } = useField('firstName');

const { handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
  validationSchema,
});
```

the code sould look like this, with `useForm` before `useField`

```
const { handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
  validationSchema,
});
const { errorMessage, meta, value: firstName } = useField('firstName');
```